# Show a polar equation describes a cylinder

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have to show that $2r+r\cos\theta =1$ describes a cylinder.

I try moving the equation to cartesian coordinates and I get$\ 3x^2+4y^2-2x=1$, after that I don't know what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Complete the squares

Comment: I did, but I got to an equation that describes an ellipse, shouldn't it be a circle?

Comment: Did you mean $...\color{red}+2x= 1$?

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: maybe it's an elliptic [cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder)

Comment: Does it need to be a circle?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$1= 3x^2+4y^2-2x=3\left(x-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2+4y^2-\dfrac{1}{3}\Rightarrow \frac{\left(x-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{3}=1.$$

Then, you have an elliptic cylinder.

Comment: Did you mean $=\dfrac19$?